# iAd banner not clickable

Tags: ios, uiview, admob, iad, adbannerview

I'm using Google AdMob mediation with the iAd adapter and standard google ads. To present the ads at the bottom im using [CJPAdController](https://github.com/chrisjp/CJPAdController)  which works fine as well.
I'm correctly receiving test ads for both networks and the google ads work perfectly when an ad is successfully received. The problem is, the iAd banners sometimes show up but aren't clickable. The banner has the dark click overlay effect but the modal fullscreen ad doesn't show up on click (tested on device iOS 7). The debug prints of CJPAdController indicate "iAd tapped"...

Sometimes though, even the iAds work fine. I have set the background color to white of every view i could find, as there seems to be a bug with this but still doesn't work.

Anyone an idea what could be the problem here? Is it the test ads and it will work in the app-store version?

Comment: Does it works "sometimes" with iAds, or never ?

Comment: sometimes, but not reproduceable sometimes ;)